# can't able to show equalizer in flutter using just_audio pakage

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I am facing error while showing equalizer.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError: audioEffectSetEnabled() has not been implemented.

my code to initialize audio player in controller class:
[image]

and the code i access my equalizer from controller class is below:
[image]

the same code is working in test implementation but not in my project i follow the code from the official example of the just-audio package

Comment: Please add more detail to your question about what you're doing (include code if relevant), and what platform you're encountering the error on.

Comment: target platform is android my problem is when i show equalizer using same code in a separate project it's work fine but when i integrate it in my music player it causing the error:

Comment: @RyanHeise is there is any platform specific integration for adding equalizer or is there any other package which causing the error

Comment: The comments section isn't intended for this, I am just trying to help you to edit your question so that someone can answer it. You still haven't edited your question with enough information, so probably nobody will be able to answer it. The only setup instructions are in the README - please edit your question in relation to everything you have done and followed.

Comment: @RyanHeise now you can check the question is updated thanks